# Does it matter for metabolism at what time of day we eat?

Tags: nutrition, metabolism

In many popular media that discuss fat loss and dieting, a common idea is that eating at the "wrong" time of the day, say a meal at dinner time, is supposedly better from a weight loss perspective than eating that same meal at another time of day, say around midnight.

Is there any research to back up statements like that? I.e., does it make a difference when in the day we eat the same food?